# Как после получения View использовать switch?

Tags: android, android-layout

Как после получения View

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_bs_lerning, null);
```

Использовать `switch` для этого `Layout`?

Чтобы было что-то типо

```
Switch(v.getid) {
    case
}
```

А то у меня не читабельный код получается 6 штук `setOnClickListener`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504160/android-use-a-switch-statement-with-setonclicklistener-onclick-for-more-than-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас все равно будет 6 вызовов `setOnClickListener`. По другому никак.
Один слушатель для нескольких view сделайте так:

```
class View.OnClickListener l = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId) {
            case R.id.view1:
                //perform logics
                break;
            case R.id.view2:
                //perform logics
                break;
            // e.t.c.
        }
    }
};
view1.setOnClickListener(l);
view2.setOnClickListener(l);
//e. t. c.
```

Answer (score 3):

Несмотря на то, что в [данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684064/223089) всё верно, если Вы хотите сделать код работы с `View` чище, настоятельно Вам советую присмотреться к библиотеке [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), она сильно экономит время и убирает лишний код.

В качестве альтернативы, можете попробовать [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) от Google, в обоих случаях вам просто не понадобятся `switch` для обработки кликов.